# Timestamp intervals processed by date() don't calculate correctly

Tags: php, timestamp, intervals

I have two unix timestamps in my database that I am subtracting to get a time interval in seconds:

```
$interval = $array["time2"] - $array["time1"]; // When echoed, $interval = 3
```

However, when I run this $interval through `date()`, like so:

```
echo date("g\h i\m", $interval);
```

these 3 seconds all of a sudden echo to:

> 7h00m

Does anyone have any idea why date() might be taking these three seconds and stretching them out into a 7 hour interval somehow?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The second argument to `date()` is a timestamp (seconds since midnight, Jan 1, 1970 GMT). Your interval is probably equating to 7am in your timezone relative to this date.

Comment: Why isn't `3` a valid timestamp? Wouldn't that represent 3 seconds after midnight Jan 1, 1970?

Comment: @esqew I updated my answer. It's probably taking into account your timezone (Cambodia, Christmas Island, Indonesia, Lao, Thailand, Vietnam?).

Comment: Oh, how annoying. I do set the timezone as such in the beginning of my file: `date_default_timezone_set('America/New_York');`

Comment: how about using the function designed for this  date_diff(), DateTime::diff()

Comment: Oooh... `date_diff()` is pretty, wasn't aware of it. ;) Thanks a lot.

Comment: Well php is just doing what you ordered.  g = 12format hours, and i = minutes.  so of course it didn't print the 3 seconds.  this just happens to be at 7am jan 1 1970?

Comment: @Dreaded I thought 7am too but it could also be 7pm Dec 31, 1969 as `g` is a 12-hour format (GMT-5 - New York as indicated)